# My C program works great when I compile it in repl.it but the do/while loop is not functioning in codeblocks

Tags: c, loops, do-while

My C intro to programming class has us use a compiler on repl.it. But me being ambitious and wanting to try and run before I crawl, I downloaded codeBlocks to learn more about IDE's in general.

Although it's a great feeling that I set up the editor and compiler by myself I am now running into a problem maybe one of you guys can answer. First of all, the code I will be sending you guys is part of a homework assignment BUT it is completed and this is not a how do I do X to get Y. This is a question about why my do/while loop works in repl.it but not codeblocks!

Second of all, here's my code:

```
int main( void )
{
  int classSel; // variable for what class consumer chooses
  int seat[SIZE] = {0}; // initializing all seats to zero or false meaning 
                        //they are empty
  char nextFlight;
  unsigned int i, j = 1, k = 6;

  do
  {
    printf( "\nChoose only available options. Enter 1 (First Class; Seats 
Left: %d) or 2 (Economy Class Seats Left: %d) ", 6 - j, 11 - k );
    scanf( "%d", &classSel );

if ( classSel == 1 )
{
  if ( seat[j] == 0 && j < 6 )
  {
    seat[j] = 1;
    printf( "\n******************\n" );
    printf( "*  COP AIRLINES  *\n" );
    printf( "*  FIRST  CLASS  *\n" );
    printf( "*   Seat No. %d   *\n", j );
    printf( "******************\n" );
    j++;
    i++;

    printf( "\n\nPage will reload for next customer...\n" );
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "First Class seats are full. Do you want Economy Class instead? (Press Y or N)");
    scanf( " %c", &nextFlight );
    if ( nextFlight == 'Y' || nextFlight == 'y')
    {
      if ( seat[k] == 0 && k < SIZE )
      {
        printf( "\nYou chose to stay on this flight! You must be ready to get where you want to go!\n");
        seat[k] = 1;
        printf( "\n******************\n" );
        printf( "*  COP AIRLINES  *\n" );
        printf( "*   ECON CLASS   *\n" );
        printf( "*   Seat No. %d   *\n", k );
        printf( "******************\n" );

        printf( "\n\nPage will reload for next customer...\n" );
        k++;
        i++;
      }
    }
    else if ( nextFlight == 'N' || nextFlight == 'n' )
    {
      printf( "\nThe next flight is in three hours. See you then!\n\nPage will reload for next customer...\n");
    }      }
}
else if ( classSel == 2 )
{
  if ( seat[k] == 0 && k < SIZE )
  {
    seat[k] = 1;
    printf( "\n******************\n" );
    printf( "*  COP AIRLINES  *\n" );
    printf( "*   ECON CLASS   *\n" );
    printf( "*   Seat No. %d   *\n", k );
    printf( "******************\n" );

    printf( "\n\nPage will reload for next customer...\n" );
    k++;
    i++;
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "Economy class seats are full. Do you want First Class instead? (Press Y or N)");
    scanf( " %c", &nextFlight );
    if ( nextFlight == 'Y' || nextFlight == 'y')
    {
      if ( seat[j] == 0 && j < 6 )
        {
          printf( "\nYou chose to upgrade on this flight. Great choice!\n" );
          seat[j] = 1;
          printf( "******************\n" );
          printf( "*  COP AIRLINES  *\n" );
          printf( "*  FIRST  CLASS  *\n" );
          printf( "*   Seat No. %d   *\n", j );
          printf( "******************\n" );

          printf( "\n\nPage will reload for next customer...\n" );
          j++;
          i++;
        }
    }
    else if ( nextFlight == 'N' || nextFlight == 'n' )
    {
      printf( "\nThe next flight is in three hours. See you then!\n\nPage will reload for next customer...\n");
    }
  }
}
  } while( i < 10 );

  printf( "Plane is full. Sorry but you must wait for the next flight. It is 
in 3 hours.\n");
}
```

For some reason it didn't like when i showed my definition for SIZE (its 11) or when I included `<stdio.h>` BUT I HAVE BOTH OF THOSE IN MY CODE MIND YOU!

Third of all, I am not looking for you to comment on how ugly and janky my code is, I'm very aware of this. All I want to know is why the do/while loop works in repl.it flawlessly but it only goes through one loop in codeBlocks.

Comment: your code is janky :)

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. What does it show you?

Comment: Post your complete code. not "for some reason it didnt like"

Comment: SIZE is undefined in the code that you provide above.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Add the #include's you are using and show us your definition of SIZE.

Comment: Size is not undefined. You did not read my comments. It didn't put it in code format and I stated I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Debugger also let me know everything was a-okay

Comment: Note that Code::Blocks is not at all relevant to whether or not your code runs.  It is only an IDE.  The relevant part perhaps  is what _compiler_ you are using with Code::Blocks.  That said in this case the behaviour is entirely undefined and may easily differ in any environment or even in the _same_ environment.  Regarding "_It didn't like it when...." - what is "it"!?  Are you referring to Code::Blocks, your compiler, StackOverflow, or something else?

Comment: @papajani : I guess you did not inspect the variables - or in the debugger they happened to have values that worked - that can happen with undefined behaviour - different execution environment, different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely reason is you don't initialize `i`

put `i = 0;`  at the top of your code ( and initialize the other variables )

some enviroments blank memory first ( make 0 ), some don't, some even initialize to non zero to make it easier to find uninitialized variable problems

Also, hopefully, your compiler should be warning you about these things, often when new you have no idea how to fix warnings, and often the code works anyways, but learn to kill all warnings, they tend to help you with issues like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to initialize the i counter to zero. Unfortunately codeBlocks did not give me this warning. Do you have any recommendations for IDEs for beginners? You also agreed my code is janky. Since you did do you have any recommendations to improve it. Keep in mind I just learned about arrays. I'm starting pointers tomorrow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the biggest thing to improve your code is to create functions and meaningful variable names.  j and k are really bad names for first class and economy seats taken.

Comment: also you have coding habits which can introduce bugs that will haunt you. You have SIZE which is total number of seats, and then hard coded numbers 6 and 11.    You'd be better off defining those.   `#define SIZE (FIRSTCLASS_SEATS + ECONOMY_SEATS)`

Comment: These are great tips. I will definitely implement these and add comments so i remember in the future. As for functions I'm still having difficulty grasping them so I need to study up on those some more

Comment: functions are almost the most important thing in software development ( there is no most important thing, but functions are just so fundamental and a lot more involved than you will first understand them to be )

Comment: Code::Blocks is not responsible for warnings - that is what the compiler does.  You need to set the warning levels and options appropriately, and some errors such as unitialised variables may only be spotted when optimisation is enabled.  It is worth running a build with optimisation if only to get deeper code analysis that can spot these errors.  Don't try to debug the optimised code however.